# How should I configure the backup of distributed queues?

Tags: gridgain

I am new for GirdGain. So far, I know GridGain cache provides backup function and I can configure backup option in configuration file. I am wondering if there is a way to configure the backup of distributed queues.

Thanks,
Bill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since distributed queues are retrieved from cache API, they inherit the number of configured backups from the cache. For more information, see [GridGain Distributed Queues](http://doc.gridgain.org/latest/Distributed+Queues) documentation.